# Credit Card payments not working Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hi I am implementing paypal API on my website where different vendors come and sell their products.Currently I am using sandbox environment.Payments are working perfectly using paypal account but payments are not working using Credit Card.Getting following error:

> We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.
>
> For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or
>   deleting cookies.
>
> Message 6838

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an issue that is happening with every transaction, make certain that you are using live credentials with live endpoints.

If you are using Express Checkout make certain you have the correct API Signature credentials.

Below are two links for going live and correct API Endpoints: 
[PayPal Developer Site, Going Live](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive)
[API Endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints)

If this is happening on only a handful of transactions it may be a technical issue.You can submit a ticket to [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/)

Comment: I am using sandbox credentials and payments are working fine using paypal account but CC payments still not working.

Comment: Are you setup with a Website Payments Pro Account or a PayPal Payments Pro Payflow edition account to process Credit Cards?